# HTML tag Font offsets layout

Tags: html, css, fonts

Have a look at the following two pictures. The first one is `<font color="#3f3fff">test</font>` while the second one is `<font style="font-size: 8px;">test</font>`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXnop.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dphf8.png

The CSS for "font" elements is as follows:

```
display: inline-block;
line-height:32px !important;
font-weight: 300;
```

The mysterious this is that as you can see, when I set the color everything is as expected, but if I set the font-size, or (not in the picture) the font-family, it adds an annoying space above it as can be seen in the second picture. I cannot figure out where it comes from as I have set the line-height. I have also checked the margin and padding for both the Font element and the parent, with no luck.

This spacing does not appear in the element inspector but in fact it does make the container enlarge by 1 or 2 pixels.

If I set it as display:block, it does not add the space but obviously it is not a desirable effect.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify `vertical-align: middle | top | bottom | {etc etc}`

you can also use vertical-align in different contexts to align elements very flexible and fine-grained. The sizes of elements need not to be known. Elements stay in the flow so other elements can react to changed dimensions of those.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `display: inline-block;` with `float: left;`

That should work. Example below:

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
  height:32px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
font{
  float:left;
  line-height:32px !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#box{
  float:left;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:yellow;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <font color="#3f3fff">test</font>
  <div id="box"><font style="font-size: 8px;">test</font></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked at first but when there are also other elements inside the wrapper it makes things messy if not using clear... But thanks anyway!

Comment: What "other elements" are there? Should cause no problems. As long has they have `float:left;` too @johndoe

Comment: @johndoe Added another element to show you, check my answer

Comment: try with the following: `<div id="container">
  <font color="#3f3fff">test</font>
  <div>
    <font color="red">test</font>
  </div>
  <font style="font-size: 8px;">test</font>
</div>` The correct behavior of the div would be to occupy the whole line and send the next element down

Comment: @johndoe Just make sure that div also has `float: left;`. Updated once again. Check it

Comment: yea, forgot to add the float to it but still it does not go to the new line!